# Laravel: Validate input only if available in DOM

Tags: laravel, validation, vuejs2, axios

I created a form with the following fields:

- Name
- Email
- Country
- City
- Address

If the user selects a country that has states (ex. United States) then the form transforms to:

- Name
- Email
- Country
- State
- City
- Address

To validate this I created a separate form request like so:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
      'name' => 'required|max:255',
      'email' => 'required|email,
      'country_id' => 'required|integer',
      'state_id' => 'nullable|integer',
      'city_id' => 'required|integer',
      'address' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

The problem is that if I leave it like that, then if I don't select a state it will pass validation.

If i make it:

```
'state_id' => 'sometimes|nullable|integer',
```

Then again it passes validation.

If I make it:

```
'state_id' => 'required|nullable|integer',
```

It will not pass validation, but then again it will throw a validation error if there is no state field in the form.

I read a lot of articles about this but nothing seems to solve it for me.

**PS1**: I want to solve this in the form request, not in the controller. I assume that an

```
if($request->has('states')){...}
```

can help, but then again, i would like to keep everything tidy in the form request.

**PS2**: I am using VueJS and Axios to add/remove states from the form. The whole form is actually a Vue component.

Any clues?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can conditionally add rules via the `sometimes` method on `Validator`.

```
$v->sometimes('state_id', 'required|integer', function ($input) {
    return in_array($input->countries, [1,2,3,4...]
});
```

You could use the `required_with` line of parameters, but because the validation is based on the value of the input instead of just the presence, the custom validation rule is probably your best bet.

Per https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

Comment: thanks for this. I will give it a try and report back!